# Golang MongoDB find, sort then insert to another collection

Tags: mongodb, go

I have a huge collection A with many documents.
Now I want to do a query to A, do some sorting, add some fields and save it to another collection B.

In SQL I can do everything in one query

```
INSERT INTO [DB].[B]
                   ([CorrelationID]
                   ,[RowNumber]
                   ,[SourceName]
                   ,SomeOther fields)
        SELECT
                    @CorrelationID
                    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SequenceNumber ASC) AS RowNumber
                    ,[SourceName]
                    ,SomeOther fields
                FROM [DB].[A]
                WHERE  [SourceName] = @SourceName
```

I want do the same thing for mongoDB with Golang.

Right now I have to find with sort options first:

```
query := bson.D{{"source", sourceName},}

sort := bson.D{{"seq_num", 1},}

opts := options.Find()
opts.SetSort(sort)

collection := getCollectionA()
cursor, err := collection.Find(context.Background(), query, opts)
```

Then I decode the data from the cursor, add fields and then save them to a slice. And then insert back with:

```
collection = getCollectionB()
result, err := collection.InsertMany(context.Background(), dataSlice)
```

Which is not ideal, I am wondering if it possible to do such logic within mongoDB i.e using one query.

Comment: This is possible using the [Aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/). The aggregation result can be directed to a collection using the [`$merge`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/#pipe._S_merge) stage.

Comment: @icza Could you post a separate answer with code snippets instead of adding a comment to the question?